# Entity Framework and LINQ with views defining Nested tables

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I am trying to get some views to form nested tables EF 6 with Dbsets, there are no FK relationships on the views in the databse and cannot be changed easily.  How can I persaude entity framework/LINQ or the models to have and load the nested table.

The classes correspond to the views.

```
public partial class Product
{
public System.Guid UniqueID { get; set; }
public string Product { get; set; }
public string Licensee { get; set; }
public string Supplier { get; set; }
public int SeatCount { get; set; }
public System.DateTime ExpiryDate { get; set; }
public System.DateTime IssueDate { get; set; }
// would like IQueryable <Component> components here I can map to a MultiSelectList
}
public Partial class Component
{
public System.Guid UniqueID { get; set; }
public System.Guid ProductID { get; set; }
public string Description;
}
```

In usage the DbSet  Products is either got as the whole list or resticted to a single supplier, then filtered for paging and searching by Product and dates.

How can I get the components collection into the Product?  I have been reading the articles on the modeller and EF but its not wuite makin sense.  The EF does not seem to like me adding a relationship between the tables either, could be as they are views?

Comment: i don't think it's possible without adding foreign key references between two table... how ef know i have to load data for Component without knowledge of id ... inner query will work here...

Comment: Th ef will not let me add the relationships, click add and nothing, most odd

Comment: check out : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.dataloadoptions.loadwith%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edited the edmx file to change store:Type="Viewss" to store:Type="Tables" , then could add on associations and generates the right objects then.

Answer (score 0):

This will be an inefficient method, but if you absolutely cannot get a foreign key between your entities you can use a [LINQ join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb311040.aspx) and a group by.

```
var query = from prod in Products
            join comp in Components on prod.UniqueID equals comp.ProductID into compGroup
            select new {
                Product= prod,
                Components = compGroup  //This will be an IEnumerable<Component>
            };
```